# Can someone understand query

Tags: sql, oracle

**Can someone understand this  query**

```
select
 nvl(
  trim(
   to_char(
    max(
     to_number(
      substr(id, 13, 4)
     ) + 1
    ), '0000'
   )
  ), '0001'
 )
from emp
where substr(id, 1, 12) = ? || ?;
```

Comment: Why have you tagged so many RDBMS types?

Comment: Basic formatting wouldn't go amiss

Comment: The query contain many nested function calls. Which one is confusing you?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at it *inside out*:

- `SUBSTR` - take 4 characters from `ID` column, starting from character position #13
- convert it to a number (`TO_NUMBER`) and add `1` to it
- get `MAX` value (calculated above) for all rows in the `EMP` table that satisfy the `WHERE` condition, i.e. whose first 12 characters of the `ID` column match `?` concatenated (`||`) with `?` (`?` is probably some parameter value)
- convert that value into a string (`TO_CHAR`)
- trim last `'0000'` characters
- finally, return value you got. If everything above returns *nothing* (`NULL`), then return `0001` (`NVL`)